# Localizable strings from JSON runtime on iOS

Tags: ios, nslocalizedstring

I have user localizable strings for the strings used in storyboard or source files which are fixed. These are defined in files like `Localizable.string` (Spanish), `Localizable.string` (German) etc. But I have a requirement where these strings can keep changing. These strings are received as a response to `REST API` call. My question is how can I use it.

Current code is `let text = NSLocalizedString("Some string", comment: "")`

Where `NSLocalizedString` looks for `Localizable.string` file. How can I make `NSLocalizedString` look for localized words from my custom dictionary/Json?

Comment: A `.strings` file with given format `"key" = "value";` is required but the name of the file can be arbitrary. For a custom name use the method `NSLocalizedString(_:tableName:bundle:value:comment:)`

Comment: Dynamically creating localisation strings are not possible directly inside the app. Either you need to pass the language and country to API you are fetching to get localized string (use third pard to get translated online, risk being we may not may not get contextually correct meaning when translated)

Answer (score 1):

Try this

First you need to copy that files in document directory .

**Get Localised Label**

```
let localisedString = self.getLocalizatioString(key: "your key", stringFileName: "test.strings") //
```

**Function**

```
func getLocalizatioString(key : String?, stringFileName : String ) -> String {
            let doumentDirectoryPath = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(.documentDirectory, .userDomainMask, true)[0] as NSString
            let destinationPath = doumentDirectoryPath.appendingPathComponent(stringFileName)
            let dict = NSDictionary.init(contentsOfFile: destinationPath)
            return (dict?.object(forKey: key!) as? String)!
        }
```

**Output**

[image]

**In String file**[image]

Comment: Can I add/remove the language dynamically? For example, I may not get french translation always but I do not want to have a default field their. I need to have multiple translations and this will change runtime.

Comment: yes you can do ...you need to download multiple string file to document directory with different name

Comment: I need to create this .strings file dynamically from the JSON I download. Is Bundle necessary here?

Comment: yes you need to send that file with specific name and get with that name

Comment: I still have the confusion. I am very new to all this. I have something like

{
"en" : "English",
"fr" : "French"
}

How can I create File.strings (English), file.strings (French) from this?

Comment: simply you can add "lanugage_name.string" while saving the file in the document directory.